Docker error - Permission denied @ rb_sysopen
I'm trying to run this in docker:
https://github.com/ytti/oxidized?tab=readme-ov-file#running-with-docker
My steps:
git clone https://github.com/ytti/oxidized
Cloning into 'oxidized'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 15154, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2162/2162), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (391/391), done.
remote: Total 15154 (delta 1836), reused 1882 (delta 1765), pack-reused 12992 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (15154/15154), 2.84 MiB | 14.52 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (9511/9511), done.

docker build -q -t oxidized/oxidized:latest oxidized/
sha256:bbf1473352184558aeb70d937d1b49ed95dad3b3d7bef005900b0d81e49111gg

mkdir /etc/oxidized

Try to run it with:
docker run --rm -v /etc/oxidized:/home/oxidized/.config/oxidized -p 8888:8888/tcp --user oxidized -t oxidized/oxidized:latest oxidized
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/oxidized/.config/oxidized/config

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks
The above steps, but get the error Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/oxidized/.config/oxidized/config

You might want to check the permissions on the /etc/oxidized directory. Make sure the docker user has access to it. You might also want to stay away from mounting stuff under /etc/ in your containers.
